# Округление чисел в C++

Tags: c++

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что VS в C++ округляет числа, которые он получает после всех вычислений. Мне этого не нужно. Как сделать, чтобы он выдавал точность вплоть до 10^-14? Потому что погрешности находятся примерно там. Я использовал для всех чисел тип float. Потом попробовал double. разницы не было.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream fmatrix("C:\\Users\\Pavel\\Desktop\\cpp1\\matrix.txt");
    ifstream ffree("C:\\Users\\Pavel\\Desktop\\cpp1\\free.txt");
    double matrix[30][30];
    double matrixCopy[30][30];
    double free[30];
    double x[30];
    double freeNew[30];
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 30; j++)
            fmatrix >> matrix[i][j];
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 30; j++)
            matrixCopy[i][j]=matrix[i][j];
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        ffree >> free[i];
    for (int k = 0; k < 29; k++) //Прямой ход Гаусса
    {
        for (int j = k + 1; j < 30; j++)
        {
            double r = matrix[j][k] / matrix[k][k];
            for (int i = k; i < 30; i++)
                matrix[j][i] -= matrix[k][i] * r;
            free[j] -= free[k] * r;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        x[i] = 0;
    for (int k = 29; k >= 0; k--)//Обратный ход Гаусса
    {
        double r = 0;
        for (int j = k + 1; j < 30; j++)
        {
            double g = matrix[k][j] * x[j];
            r += g;
        }
        x[k] = (free[k]-r) / matrix[k][k];;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        freeNew[i] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 30; j++)
            freeNew[i] += matrixCopy[i][j] * x[j];
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        cout << freeNew[i] << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Как вы установили, что происходит округление?

Comment: @tutankhamun На паре нам сообщили, что уже проверяли все матрицы 30х30 - ответы точно должны быть с минимальной погрешностью. Наша цель - вытащить эту погрешность.

Comment: Есть float, есть double, и есть спец-методы работы с числами большой разрядности. Есть комплексные числа, есть работа с числами представлеными в массиве, "ручное" умножение/деление. Определитесь с задачей, может даже укажите формулу которую считаете. И желательно с методикой. Если вы изучаете работу с числами таким то методом - то вам нужен именно этот метод. Напишите кусок кода где вы считаете результат.

Comment: Матрицы считайте "простыми дробями" (если это метод Гауса) - тогда результат будет точный. Иначе там идёт большая потеря точности, и double не поможет.

Comment: Есть у меня нехорошее подозрение, что вы имеете в виду **вывод** значений на экран с 6 знаками, и называете это округлением... Если выводите через `cout<<`, то посмотрите в сторону `setprecision`...

Comment: Код то покажите.

Comment: `long double ` не пробовали ?

Comment: хотя сам double 16 знаков после запятой. что удовлетворяет условию 10^-14

Answer (score 1):

возможно, что в двоичном представлении ваше какое то число  является бесконечной периодической дробью. И при конечной длине мантиссы не может быть представлена точно. попробуйте другие числа или все таки long double, у которой 20 знаков после запятой

```
cout<< setprecision(14) <<  freeNew[i] << endl; // 14, потому что вы 14 знаков хотите после запятой
```